# CSS transition property is not working properly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to add **transition** property using css which is not working properly, I am giving my html & css code below :

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="job-tile">
    <li style="background-color:#000" class="active" id="sw_start">Tile 1</li>
    <li style="background-color:#000" class="active" id="sw_start">Tile 1</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
.job-tile 
{ 
    position:relative; 
    list-style:none; 
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.job-tile li
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 12px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight:normal;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.job-tile li:hover
{
    opacity:1 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
    transition: background-color 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}
```

**If I put a background color on hover property, it will works fine, but I want to place opacity in on hover.any idea?**
I am also giving working js fiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/4Qcr3/1/

Comment: There is no need to specify `transition` more than once. Just specifying it on `.job-tile li` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transition-property` you set is not enough (missing the `opacity` property), you should use the `all` keyword instead. Also the `transition` is not fully implemented by all browsers, you should add vendor prefixes to make it function cross-browser well:

```
.job-tile li {
   ...
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.job-tile li:hover {
   opacity:1 !important;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;    
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Qcr3/4/)

Comment: `-ms-transition` is not needed.

Comment: This is correct... Also, in your HTML both of your `li`s have the same ID of 'sw_start'.  No two elements should have the same ID.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't get update well with the vendors, maybe IE has implemented it fully, thanks!

Comment: @King King: The prefix was only used in pre-release versions of IE10. The RTM version uses unprefixed transitions going forward.

Comment: @PatrickAllen I did not notice the html code, however it should be corrected by the OP, thanks!

Comment: @KingKing No worries, I wasn't correcting you... It was just something I caught when I looked at the fiddle.  Good work